# Custom cell in tableView in ios 5

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uilabel

I am trying to reduce the cell's one label's width  at particular indexPath.row but its not working..
below i added code for that and I am using iOs 5 storyboard.
Any one have other way to change the size of label at run time  ??

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"name&email"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


}
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *detail = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    nameLabel.text = @"Name : ";
    detail.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 1){
    nameLabel.text = @"Email : ";
     detail.text = @"";
}else if(indexPath.row == 2){
    nameLabel.text = @"Location Alerts";
    detail.text = @"Notifies people when they are close to a saved spot";
// here i am changing the width of lable
    detail.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 0);
}else if(indexPath.row == 3){
    nameLabel.text = @"Share This App :";
    detail.text = @"(post to facebook/twitter)";
}else if(indexPath.row == 4){
    nameLabel.text = @"Review This App :";
    detail.text = @"(on iTunes)";
}else if(indexPath.row == 5){
    nameLabel.text = @"Get Help :";
    detail.text = @"(send an email to me)";
}
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I'm seeing that you are using two differents identifier.

If I were you I would try:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"name&email";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"name&email"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }
```

ok? Tell me if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the custom cell created in Storyboard, check what the **Identifier** is and use that. The **Identifier** should be under the **Attributes Inspector**. If the **Identifier** is **Cell**, then your code should be something like this to get the Cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

If you have a UILabel called **detail** which you want to change the width of, you can change the **size** by changing the **frame** and reusing the previous **frame origin** and **size height**.

```
detail.frame = CGRectMake(detail.frame.origin.x, detail.frame.origin.y, newWidth,detail.frame.size.height);
```

Make sure you pass `detail.size.height` as the height, to keep the height the same (I noticed in your example that the height is 0 which wouldn't make it visible). Hope that helps